# TestCafe - Cannot switch to the window when running test in pipeline

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

[image]

I've encountered a problem when using TestCafe in Bitbucket Pipeline. It shows "Cannot switch to the window" when running test. Why does this happen and what does this mean? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The test application opens a new window on the `click(Selector('.smile-list'))` and tries to switch to the opened window to continue test execution. The switching timeout is 20 second. Please check the test execution locally. If the issue is reproduced, please create an issue in TestCafe repository and share an example. If not, try to improve the test website's performance.